# Three Displays: HDMI(TV), VGA(LCD) and Laptop

Tags: windows, laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I tried all combinations. If HDMI and VGA work, the laptop is blank, if Laptop and HDMI work, VGA is blank. And obviously, the third obvious combination.

Computer Specification: INTEL 4000 SEries Graphic card

Plus: AMD Radeon HD 8600M Series Graphic Card.

> dxdiag alwasys shows Intel Graphic Card Though, but the Device Manager Verifies ATI card.

How to get the three displays working?

Two work. But the third goes blank.

Changing Properties says, Try a different combination.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: You probably can't.  Just because a machine has multiple video outputs doesn't mean you can use all of them simultaneously.  Your machine might not support enough pipelines to push the LCD, HDMI and VGA all at the same time

Answer (score 1):

are those 3 devices shown on Display properties? If yes, two should be more like "blue" meaning they are active, and 1 which is not working should be greyed out. I've seen this on desktop PCs.

But as you are using a laptop with 8600M series graphics cards, it supports only [**up to 2 displays**](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/notebook/8500m-8600m#)